# how to load XML and XSLT files into a browser

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have created an XML and XSL file to be loaded onto a webpage as HTML. for some reason this is not working .. the data isn't being displayed in a table on to a web browser.

Here is my code below, is there anything that i am missing? please help?

XML file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="skymovies.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<collection>
  <film>
    <title>Happy Gilmore</title>
    <year>1991</year>
    <genre>Comedy</genre>
  </film>
  <film>
    <title>Rango</title>
    <year>1991</year>
    <genre>Comedy</genre>
  </film>
  <film>
    <title>Happy Gilmore</title>
    <year>1991</year>
    <genre>Comedy</genre>
  </film>
  </movie>
</collection>
```

XSLT file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="IS0-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/collection">
    <html>
    <body>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>Genre</th>
        </tr>

        <xsl:for-each select="film">
         <xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
         <xsl:value-of select="year" /></td>
         <xsl:value-of select="genre" /></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is there anythig i'm doing wrong? please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML is not valid. You have a `</movie>` in your XML which has no opening tag. Try using this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="skymovies.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<collection>
  <film>
    <title>Happy Gilmore</title>
    <year>1991</year>
    <genre>Comedy</genre>
  </film>
  <film>
    <title>Rango</title>
    <year>1991</year>
    <genre>Comedy</genre>
  </film>
  <film>
    <title>Happy Gilmore</title>
    <year>1991</year>
    <genre>Comedy</genre>
  </film>
</collection>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XSLT is not valid either: you have closing `</td>` tags that you never opened. You also forgot to create a row for each film. It should look something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/collection">
    <html>
    <body>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>Genre</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="film">
        <tr>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="year" /></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="genre" /></td>
         </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying .. but this seems not to work either. just to clarify, I am running this in Internet explorer by just double clicking on the .xml file. is this the right way to the run these files?

Comment: Not to worry sir the solution you offered is now working ! thank you! God bless!

Comment: Running these files by clicking in a browser is fine once they are working, but as you're discovering, it's not a very friendly environment for debugging. If you're the sort of person who sometimes makes mistakes, then you'll find that developing XSLT code in a tool such as Stylus Studio or oXygen is much more productive.

Comment: @MichaelKay Please address your comment to the OP.